# Error SiteMap

Tags: asp.net, sitemappath

What is this error when I SiteMapPath and Configure whit siteMap.of course when I upload my website,I showing this error : "The page cannot be found

### The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Please try the following:

Make sure that the Web site address displayed in the address bar of your browser is spelled and formatted correctly. 
If you reached this page by clicking a link, contact the Web site administrator to alert them that the link is incorrectly formatted. 
Click the Back button to try another link. 
HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)
"
What Do I do that SiteMap work correctly ?

Comment: What sitemap do you mean? Google site map or from any programming technology, for example .NET?

Comment: So locally all works fine, but on the hosting you have following error?

Comment: yes I have this error in host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a critical question and something to try:

### Does the website work on your development machine?

1. If it does work then check the url for the pages in the SiteMap.  If the URL for the pages in the SiteMap reference a physical directory such as  "**C:\mySite\MyPage.aspx**" then that is the most likely cause.  You want to ensure that the URLs refernce the page location through a relative path like "**~/MyPage.aspx**".
2. If it does not work, then verify that there are no typing errors in the URLS.  Once you getting it working on a local development environment using relative paths then the chance of it working on a remote machine should go up considerably.